# Flutter session timeout using timer not working while there's no user interaction or app is in background

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm using **Timer** to logout inactive user while they're logged in or the app is in background with logged in. This worked sometimes while user remaining inactive after logged in and working into app but not all times and also not working while the app is in background it's not auto log out user specially in iOS. I've found that Timer gives inappropriate result into iOS while the app is in background.

```
  Timer? _timer;
  void _initializeTimer() {
    if (_timer != null) {
      _timer!.cancel();
    }
   
    final DateTime _sessionStartTime = DateTime.now();
    final Duration _sessionTimeoutDuration = Duration(minutes: Constants.autoLogOutTime);
    _timer = Timer(_sessionTimeoutDuration, () {
      // Check if the session has timed out.
      final todayDate = DateTime.now();
      if (todayDate.difference(_sessionStartTime) > _sessionTimeoutDuration) {
        _logOutUser();
      }
    });
  }
```

```
  void _handleUserInteraction([_]) {
    _initializeTimer();
  }
```

```
return GestureDetector(
  behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
  onTap: _handleUserInteraction,
  onPanDown: _handleUserInteraction,
  onPanUpdate: _handleUserInteraction,
  child: MaterialApp(...
```

How to resolve the issue for both android and iOS so that session logout worked properly according to the logout time given for inactive users.

Comment: Timers will not continue to count while your app is suspended (not the active app). You should keep a `Date` for when the user was last active and have a short timer that fires repeatedly when the app is in the foreground; if the elapsed time is greater than your time out period then log them out.  Each time the user is active, update the last active date.

Comment: @Paulw11, I've added the check but not working all the time. Please have a look the code(I've added it to answer for readability). While I'm keeping minimize the app and open another app to copy some text and  came back to my app after a while found the app is logged out already before the given inactive user activity logout time.

Comment: Don't add an answer [edit] your question to provide more details.

Comment: @Paulw11, I've updated the post. Please have a look.